# scan value to textbox, value have '~' so language is change C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I use barcode scanner scan for value and push in `textbox1` (can scan barcode and QR Code).

My computer have two language that is '**Eng**' and '**Thai**'.
I use the button `~` (tilde) to change the language.
So when I scan the QR Code. In some value is have `~` between the word so it changes the system language and the value changes to **Thai** language immediately.

E.g.: I push tilde button for change language to English before and scan value in QR Code is `AAA~MMM`. But `textbox1` shows `AAAททท`.

I tried change the button for change language is `window+spacebar`. When I scanned it is correct value and the system language doesn't change anymore.

But if I don't wanna change the button to change language. Who have the idea how to fix the `textbox1` when find the `~` value will don't change and system language don't change and have correct value.

Comment: Too bad. Many barcode scanners act as a keyboard wedge and thus their input is interpreted as keyboard input. This is an example of why ALWAYS use key combinations for special functions. The alternative is to use a scanner that doesn't interact with the system that way.

Comment: whaaa .... Thank you @jmcilhinney . I just understand the act of the barcode scanners.
so It's have only one way... Change the button of change language.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `~` from the text in `textbox1`.
apply this algorithm on your text before using it and you are done.

Use:

```cs
string txt = textbox1.text;
foreach(char c in txt){
 if(c == '~')
   txt = txt.Replace(c.toString(),String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: There’s absolutely no need to iterate over the characters of the input. Just do the replacement directly.

Comment: There are several issues with this. Firstly, the issue occurs when the character is input, so taking it out later is of no value. Secondly, taking the character out at any stage changes the data, so that can't really be a good thing. Thirdly, even if you trap the character when it's input into the control, it may still be that the virtual key press has been processed by the OS and the language still changed.